# CSS image button not right

Tags: css, image, button

Go this tag:

`<a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('_paypal').submit(); return false;"><span id="order_now_btn">Order Now</span></a>`

Here's the CSS:

```
#order_now_btn {
  background: transparent url("../images/order_now_btn.gif") 0 0px no-repeat;
  height: 33px;
  width: 111px;
  display: block;
  font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor:pointer;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Problem is, I can't get the text to fit in the right place...

Here's the button image:

[image: order_now_btn.gif]

Is there a better way to do this? I have quite a few of these to do.

Comment: are they links or submit buttons? if they're buttons you should use the <input type="submit" /> or <button type="submit">...</button>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to go with the button tag, this works great.

`<button type="submit" id="order_now_btn" width="111" height="33" align="absmiddle" alt="Order Now" /><span>Order Now</span></button>`

```
#order_now_btn {
  color: #fff;
  background: transparent url("../images/order_now_btn.gif") 0 0px no-repeat;
  border: 0;
  height: 33px;
  width: 111px;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
}

#order_now_btn span {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
}
```

Comment: +1 A button is much more suited to something that's an action than a fake-link. You don't need the `width`, `height` or `align` attributes though (they don't do anything on a `<button>` anyway). And it would be nice to use a normal form submit button so that it'd work without JavaScript enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add some padding:

```
padding:10px 0 0 30px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6fX5v/

Answer (score 0):

You have to position the text above the image.

Check these

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/textoverimage/

http://frinity.blogspot.com/2008/06/placing-text-over-image-using-css.html

Answer (score 0):

just add `padding-left:30px;` and `padding-top:10px;` in `#order_now_btn` .This will position your text in the correct place.